# MQTT to Flask server on raspberry pi problem

Tags: python, html, flask, mqtt, raspberry-pi4

I have an esp32 with some sensors that i use as a weather station, it publishes to my raspi via mqtt (mosquitto), that part works fine!

I would like to be able to fetch the mqtt messages and add them to my webpage (flask webserver).

The esp32 and the raspi are at home, the flask server being on the raspi at home as well!

But i want to publish weather metrics (temp/humidity/pressure/luminosity, etc...)on my website (ssh-3d.com), which is hosted at a data center (ovh)

Thanks for your help!

:::python
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_mqtt import Mqtt
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MQTT_BROKER_URL'] = '198.168.8.136'
app.config['MQTT_BROKER_PORT'] = 1883
app.config['MQTT_USERNAME'] = 'esp32'
app.config['MQTT_PASSWORD'] = 'olayann'
app.config['MQTT_REFRESH_TIME'] = 1.0  # refresh time in seconds
mqtt = Mqtt(app)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
led1 = 6
led2 = 13


# Set each pin as an output and make it low:
GPIO.setup(led1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(led2, GPIO.OUT)

@app.route("/")

def main():
   return render_template('main.html')

def handle_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    mqtt.subscribe('home/livingroom/temperature')
    mqtt.subscribe('home/livingroom/humidity')
```

and the html part:

```
:::html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<head>
<title>My Raspberry Pi Webserver with Flask at home ! ;)</title>
<meta name="viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>
<style>
.row {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}
.column {
flex: 33%;
padding: 10px;
}
</style>
<body style="background: white">
<h1 align="center"; style="color: navy"><u>My first try using Flask, so design can be improved!</u></h1>
<br>
<br>
<h2 align="center"> Click the button below to turn on/off LEDs on my breadboard</h2>

<div align="center">
<div class="column">
<h3>Temperature is: {{home/livingroom/temperature}} Celsius</h3>
<br>
<br>
<h3>Humidity is: {{home/livingroom/humidity}} %</h3>
<h3 style="color: blue">Led 01
<button>
<a href="/pin1/on" style="color: green"> ON</a>
</button>
```